# WSO2 ESB: Usage of https client certificate in mediation

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I was planning the following setup:

- A proxy service in WSO2 ESB that interacts with a backend service via JMS.
- Proxy service clients connects to the WSO2 ESB using https with mutual authentication.
- Within the proxy service mediators, information from the client's certificate are needed.

Is there some way the client certificate could be made available to mediators?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide client certificates provided at mediator level. Medeators are put together in a pipes & filter chain, and it is the endpoint at the end that connects to the back-end and it is at the endpoint level, you have to secure it. The blog post on [How to invoke secured backend service using WSO2 ESB](http://www.soasecurity.org/2012/11/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service.html) shows how to ahcive this.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enable mutual authentication in WSO2 ESB.If you do not know how to do that please refer [Enable Mutual SSL for Proxy services in WSO2ESB](http://www.soasecurity.org/2012/08/enable-mutual-ssl-for-proxy-services-in.html).Then refer following block post to know [how to get client's certificate in class mediator](http://chamaraanu-chamarasblog.blogspot.com/2013/01/wso2-esb-class-mediator-to-check-ssl.html)